# Add two external variables via list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

im learning list comprehension but don't know if i can add a sum two variables via list comprehension to a list.
So is it possible to express below code in a list comprehension?

```
#Make some rolls, and store the results in a list.
#die_1 & die_2 represent D6 dices, .roll() is a .choice() generated from import random

results = []

for roll_num in range(1_000):
    result = die_1.roll() + die_2.roll()
    results.append(result)
```

Comment: `results = [die_1.roll() + die_2.roll() for _ in range(1_000)]`

Comment: Note that if you wanted to roll lots of dice (say, 10d6 for fireball damage), you could even have a generator inside a sum inside a list comprehension: `results = [sum(d6.roll() for _ in range(10)) for _ in range(1_000)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most concise way of doing this would be:

```py
results = [ die_1.roll() + die_2.roll() for _ in range(1_000) ]
```

For each of the 1000 iterations, both dice are rolled and their values are summed and stored in the list.

Comment: Hello thanks!
So "_" is a placeholder in that case and referres to the expression in front the "for-loop" ?

Comment: Yup. Basically tells the interpreter "the index isn't important to me, so don't even allocate any memory for it."